# Date Converting

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a String `30-07-2013` I want to convert in to `30 June`.
I am using

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"30-07-1983"];
```

They Show response `1984-12-24 18:06:32 +0000`

Comment: This question was asked more than thousand times here. Have u googled it?. Use the proper date format.

Comment: Just updated the answer of Nandana..

Comment: The point being that the format you use has to match that of the data string you have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"30-07-2013"];

 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];
NSString *strDate=[dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"strDate : %@",strDate);
```

Comment: You should use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`. Both are not same

Comment: "dd MMM" format returns Month name in 3 Characters only. Please try below code if you want full name of month.

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @MalavSoni To get the month full name, Just add one more "M", date format of "MMMM" will do the job

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"30-07-1983"];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth) fromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%d %@",(int)[components day],[[[NSDateFormatter new] monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(components.month-1)]);
```